# foreach выводит последнею запись

Tags: php, foreach

Всем привет, есть такой код:

```
    <?php
$poisk = 229786213;
$row = file('fren.txt');


foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
  $baza = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?user_id=".$value."&access_token=0$token&v=5.80"));
  if(isset($baza->response->items)){


  $array = $baza ->response->items;
  $key = array_search($poisk, $array); // $key = 2;
  if($key != FALSE){
             $fp = fopen("counter.txt", "a+");
                $mytext = "$value \r\n";
                    $test = fwrite($fp, $mytext); 
                      fclose($fp); 
                      echo "Good";

        }
      }
}


?>
```

Как сделать так, что foreach сохранил все значения, а не только последнее?

Answer (score 0):

Я вижу несколько проблемных мест.
1) В row (то есть в fren.txt) может быть одна записью Сделайте echo $row
2) Содержимое $baza>response->items не установлено, кроме одного раза
3) array_search постоянно возвращает FALSE, кроме одного раза

Ваше решение при прочих равных тоже должно работать, но все-таки лучше открывать/закрывать файл за циклом.

```
$filename = "counter.txt";
$fp = fopen($filename, "a+");
if( $fp )
{
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        //...
        $test = fwrite($fp, $mytext); 
        //...
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Не могу открыть файл";
    }
    fclose($fp); 
}
```

Comment: Увы, но это также не сохраняет все.

Comment: Отредактировал ответ

Comment: У меня указан полный путь. И проблема тут не в открытии /закрытии файла. А в том, что foreach по дефолту хранит только последнее значение. И то что я перенесу открытие файла, мне не поможет.

Comment: Я отредактировал ответ

Answer (score 0):

Блин, код "вырви глаз". PHP7 на дворе а вы пишете как в прошлом веке. Приведу пример как бы написал я:

```
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    $baza = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://..."),true);        # Возвращает массив а не объект
    if( !@array_search($poisk, $baza['response']['items']) ) continue;  # Пропускаем шаг цикла если ничего не найдено
    file_put_contents("counter.txt", "$value \r\n", FILE_APPEND);          # Дописываем в конец файла
    echo "Good";    
}
```